# How to get current layout on android?

Tags: android, android-layout

my app always different layout

`A.xml` , `B.xml` , `C.xml`

I want when current layout `A` and `B` execute `disconnect()` method.

so, How to get current layout on android?

Comment: Question is not clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try these:

```
View currentView = this.getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content)
```

or

```
View currentView = this.findViewById(android.R.id.content)
```

or

```
View currentView = this.findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView()
```

or

You can get the view if you put an id to each of your layout file's root tag like below:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_root_one"
```

And then get the view:

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rl_root_one);
```

Using any of the above methods you can get the current View inflated.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
this.getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content)
```

OR this

```
this.findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView()
```